# “preliminary” usage

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, difference

I’m writing an article and in the article I’m just talking about 4 general skills that people should learn ‘before’ they can work on the main specific skill for recovering from a loss. learning these skills helps them gain the main recovery skill a lot easier and more effectively.
Is using the word ‘preliminary’ common and appropriate for these 4 skills. For example, it’ll be like this:

-preliminary skill 1: acceptance

-preliminary skill 2:
distancing from thoughts
.
.
is “preliminary” a word that even an uneducated person can understand its meaning easily?

the other options are :

“Preparatory skills”
or
“General mental skills”

Answer (score 0):

The word **foundation** is in common use. A foundation course of study covers basic material which is essential for in-depth study. Here, you could call these **foundation skills**.

[Cambridge on line](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/foundation) has

> **foundation**
> an idea or fact that something is based on